# Symfony1.4 web configuration on server

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I upload my Symfony1.4 into my server. Url like test.domainname.com/web will access the application but i want test.domainname.com/. Where exactly change please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `DocumentRoot` of `test.domainname.com` host in Apache's configuration (or other webserver's you use).

It's hard to say where exactly it should be modified without knowledge about your server environment settings.